Irreducible power series over the integers with all rreducible reductions
Does there exist an irreducible power series $f \in \mathbb{Z}[[x]]$, such that $f$ is reducible modulo every power of $x$? That is, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exist non-unit $g_n,h_n \in \mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ with $f \equiv g_nh_n$ modulo $x^n$.
I expect such an element exists, but I'm not sure. There is a lot of literature about irreducibility criteria in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$, but I could not see an immediate way to deduce the answer from known results.
